# How to apply Vuetify to imported components from other projects

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

say I've got vue projects in this sctructure:

```
dist/
project1
project2
project3
coolProject1
dumbProject1
```

Im adding veutify to coolProject1 but it uses components from project2 (that are used in other projects). How can I get vuetify to apply styles to the imported components from a different project or projects?

Comment: I should clarify the components in project2 that are used - are being pulled in/resolved  by webpack